# Filter products by category filters, create dynamic filter with using category filter for get products, products have more filters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, filter, pivot-table

Tables

products:
-id
-status
-name_product

filters:
-id
-name
-category_filter_id

category_filters:
-id
-name

category_product (pivot table):
-id
-product_id
-filter_id

[image]

```
//Model Product
public function filters()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Filter::class);
}
//Model Filter
public function products()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
public function categoryfilter()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\CategoryFilter', 'categ_filter_id');
}
//Model CategoryFilter
public function filters()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Filter');
}
```

How to get the products if the user chooses the following:
If check: model 1, model 2, tip 2 -> the result must be: product in Model (model 1 AND/OR model 2 AND tip 2) ??

I using select:

```
$filter_ids = [23,12,43];//id filters
$products = Product::where('status', "=", 1);
$products = $products->whereHas('filters', function($query) use ($filter_ids){
    $query->whereIn('categ_filter_id', $filter_ids);
});
```

But if return the product which is at least once in the table pivot, but I need to return all the logical results.

Finally, I have to return the following: the products found in model_1 and type_2 but also the products in model_2 and type_2.
Please help me...

This dynamic filter has many categories, he need to work as a normal filter(logical).....
What do I have to do, or what is wrong?

Comment: `... WHERE model IN (1,2) AND tip = 2` .  I leave it to you to convert to Laravel.

Comment: model and tip is not a table, is a item in table category_filters.


but I don't know how many filter categories the user will choose, because they are items in table category_filters, I  it hard to make a selection